# Cannot find an initializer for type

Tags: ios, swift, initializer

I'm getting an error saying

> Cannot find an initializer for type 'SmileyScene' that accepts an
>   argument list of type '(fileNamed: String)'

I'm new to swift please help.

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

introLabel?.runAction(fadeOut, completion: {
let doors = SKTransition.doorwayWithDuration(2.0)
let smileyScene = SmileyScene(fileNamed: "SmileyScene")
self.view?.presentScene(smileyScene, transition: doors)
```

Comment: Please include your implementation of `SmileyScene`.

Comment: try to add `import SpriteKit` in your `SmileyScene `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that the type `SmileyScene` does not declare an initializer with the arguments you are trying to use to initialize your `smileyScene` constant.

Make sure that your implementation of `SmileyScene` contains the appropriate initializer and that the initializer is visible to "the outside world." That is, the initializer should not be marked `private`.